# How to keep virtual IP when port fowarding

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, port-forwarding

I have a server running in a virtual machine and the internal IP keeps changing frequently making it basically impossible to forward a port.

How do I go about solving this problem?

Also I am new to networking so forgive me if it's a simple answer or I am not specific enough.

Comment: Stop changing the internal IP address.

Comment: Yeah why is the internal IP changing?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to port forward, then you should assign the virtual machine a fixed IP address.  For Ubuntu this can be done in the file `/etc/network/interfaces`.  Consult the documentation presented by the command `man interfaces`

Choose an IP address on your subnet not served by DHCP.  Alternatively, you can configure your DHCP to serve the virtual machine a static IP address.  Depending on your virtualization container, you may be able to configure it in the virtual machine definition.